# Buscar las 5 listas con más items dentro de otra lista

Tags: lista

Tengo una clase llamada Personaje que tiene como atributo una lista de series en la cuál aparece ese personaje.
Estoy en un proyecto de Spring Boot y necesito hacer una llamada a la api para que me consiga los 5 personajes que más series tengan y me he quedado en blanco!!!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Primeramente recupero todos los personajes y los añado a una lista.
Y luego recorro la lista de personajes y miro el .size() de sus listas de series, a partir de ahí y no sé como debería recoger los 5 personajes con el .size() más alto y añadirlos en la lista theBest.
Alguien sabe como hacerlo?
PD: Ese if() está por estar

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. El código de la pregunta debe ir en formato texto y no en imagen. Haz clic en [edit] y cambia lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: En cuanto a tu duda, ordena la lista de mayor a menor de acuerdo al valor de `size()`, de esta forma puedes recuperar los 5 primeros de dicha lista. Saludos

Comment: listPersonajes.sort((a, b) -> a.getSeriesList().size().compareTo(b.getSeriesList().size())); Esta es mi idea pero no me deja aplicar el compareTo con el size